# Parse img from RSS description tag with SAX

Tags: android, rss, saxparser

Looking around i have found many tutorials about rss and img parsing from the inside of the description tag. My problem is that the app i m developing is homework for my college and i can only use SAX and not jSON as in the most examples. My RSS is working fine,but i cant load images..

So,my answers are two:

1)How to parse image from the description tag and

2)How to load it in the RSS activity.

Comment: You cant use jsoup parser or anything of that nature? And BTW what school offer's android dev as a degree or area of study?

Comment: Jsoup uses DOM. It just gets the HTML and the you can use selector's to select certain tags and text.

Comment: there is no any way to fix it in the way i m trying?i m sorry but i dont believe that an external .jar will be acceptable for my lesson...:(

Comment: check my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31744680/4845324

Answer (score 1):

Try android.util.Xml . And take a look here how to use it http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html